# How does one configure msbuild to deal with binary dependencies shared by multiple projects?

Tags: msbuild

I have a project (let's call it `a.csproj`) which has some binary items that get copied to the output directory. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(ReferenceDir)\7z.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have a second project (let's call it `b.csproj`) which happens to depend on the same binary items. So `b.csproj` also contains this `<Content>` item in an `<ItemGroup>`.

I have a third project which depends on both `a.csproj` and `b.csproj`. I start a build of this project like this:

```
PS> MSBuild.exe c.csproj /p:Platform=x86`;Configuration=Release /m
```

When I do this, both dependencies try to build in parallel. As a result, they both try to copy the same file to the same output location, which causes builds to randomly fail.

Is there some kind of mechanism I can use to declare to MSBuild that I'm okay with only one of these copies? (It seems to have no problem avoiding rebuilding `.csproj`es with complex dependency graphs; so I'm hoping to use the same mechanism here)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's all there is to it? The reason being, the `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` target  is not parallelizable, it collects all of copy-local items and does one final copy in a single step, sequentially, there shouldn't be any locks there. If you override `OutputPath` with a global property and force every one of them to be built into the same folder, then, well, that's the reality of parallelization, you can't get around it, but depending on which version of MSBuild and `Microsoft.Common.targets` you're using you can play around with `CopyRetryCount` and `CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds` properties used in `Copy` task to power through the locks or try various `CreateHardLinksFor*`, e.g. `CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible`

Comment: Within a project it is not parallelizable. But the projects themselves are parallelizable